# bare and non-bare repository on the same server for the same project

Tags: git

I have a bare repository on a server (call it test server) that I use to sync my projects across the developers team. Each developer can push and pull from this repository and sync master and branches accordingly.
For each project I have a `/home/serveruser/project.git` folder with a hook to write files to `/var/www/html/project`
From this bare repository I then push to production server (master only) where I have the same architecture. The reason why I have two servers is that I'd like to test branches centrally and not only on the developers machines (I have some people with a tester role in my team). Actually they can do it with master only before I push to production.

I cannot do checkout with a bare repository, I know it so I was thinking about adding a non bare repository in sync with the bare one. Developers will keep pushig on the bare one and tester will checkout branches on the non-bare one (all on the same server). But how do I do it? Or is there a better way for this?

I don't think I am the only one with this kind of requirement but all the solutions I have seen are hacks to perform a checkout on a bare repository and I don't like this kind of approach

Comment: What you want is not unheard of, but usually the "second repo with a checkout" is effectively created by some kind of CI server. So in a sense, what you're asking is basically continuous build/continuous integration software.

Comment: ok thanks @JoachimSauer , I know post about suggesting sw are off topic here but can you give me just a couple of names to start looking at? As you understand I'm pretty new at this while setting up my startup

Comment: @JoachimSauer are you referring to something like jenkins?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is a common one, others are available. I've not really investigated the available ones recently, so Jenkins is the only one that I have some familiarity with (but it's not necessarily the best).

Comment: jenkins, travis-ci, circle-ci, are examples of common ci services.